# Angular Form Control returning default value instead of value

Tags: angular, typescript

Any idea why Commission form control returning the value 0 instead of a calculated number?

```
 InfoForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({

        Commission: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }],
        accountCommissionPercentage : [{ value: 10, disabled: true }],
        totalComm: [{ value: 5000, disabled: true }],
 });

<input type="text" formControlName="Commission"  class="form-control" value=" {{InfoForm.accountCommissionPercentage * (InfoForm.controls.totalComm.value / 100) | number : '1.2-2'}}">
```

Comment: That's because, commission value assigned to in form is zero

Comment: Try `{{ (InfoForm.controls.accountCommissionPercentage.value * (InfoForm.controls.totalComm.value / 100)) | number : '1.2-2'}}` this.

Comment: if you use formControlName **not** use value